# Макеты советов для вопросов/ответов

Tags: обсуждение

Многие вопросы/ответы не очень соответствуют по качеству, но вполне допустимы на сайте и мы проходим мимо, а пользователи продолжают давать такие вопросы/ответы. Мне кажется, что стоит добавить макеты советов для пользователей.

*К примеру для вопроса:*

> Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него конкретную
>   проблему, которая возникла у вас в процессе решения данной задачи. В
>   противном случае, вопрос может быть закрыт проверяющими. Чтобы
>   редактировать вопрос, нажмите на кнопку [Edit]. Так же можете
>   ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший
>   вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). - [Из очереди
>   проверок](link)

*Или для ответов:*

> Пожалуйста, опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы
>   пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ. Для редактирования ответа,
>   нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как
>   написать хороший
>   ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди
>   проверок](link)

*Или такой:*

> Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям
>   было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так
>   же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший
>   ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди
>   проверок](link)

Как вы считаете, нужно ли добавлять блок с макетами советов по улучшению вопроса/ответа, чтобы проверяющие могли с лёгкость дать совет пользователю?

Я предлагаю внести списки с советами в отдельные окна (как править или отметить тревогой) и разместить вместе с остальными кнопками под вопросами/ответами. Так же внести специальные кнопки в очереди проверок.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1225/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: @alexolut, я не про комментарии, а про советы. Тогда и сообщение, когда голосуешь за закрытие - это комментарий.

Comment: А где эти советы предполагается отображать?

Comment: @alexolut, там же где и "правка" с "закрыть". И в очереди проверок. В основном в очереди

Comment: Если это подразумевает изменения в движке сайта (а судя по всему это так), то все наши обсуждения тут с вероятностью 99.9% не будут даже рассмотрены власть имущими. Как минимум следует задать вопрос на [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) чтобы на что-то надеяться. Предварительно убедившись, что подобного предложения ещё не возникало.

Comment: @alexolut, так может имеет смысл для начала оформить идею здесь? Чтобы идти к дядькам с предложением, а не с намёками.. Давайте обсудим, гипотетически.. Как эта фича должна выглядеть, чтобы быть удобной и полезной.

Comment: @vp_arth развить и обсудить безусловно можно и тут. Но чтобы хоть немного надеятся на реализацию - придется формулировать на английской части сети.

Comment: Хорошую идею всегда можно до расширения откатить)

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Если вы про шаблонные комментарии, то список мы уже ведем. Если вы про автоматически добавляемые комментарии из очереди, то необходимо менять перевод текущих. Или вы про что–то еще?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я про то, чтобы когда в очереди проверок сообщение не очень качественное, но и закрывать не за что, то можно было нажать на специальную кнопку и оттуда дать какой-то совет пользователю (типа как список причин при нажатии на кнопку "закрыть"). А если пользователь не отреагировал на советы (несколько советов), то уже тогда закрывать.